# Python Trying to read json file and print specific information

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

So, I need to load specific "questions" from a json file, when I loaded it, it just shows this: {'Question1': 'What is your name?'}. How do I make it just show "What is your name"?

My Code:

```
import json
with open("main.json", "r") as f:
    responses = json.load(f)
    print(responses)
```

Json File:

```
{
  "Question1": "What is your name?"
}
```

Comment: print(responses['Question1'])

Comment: IS there are 10 questions, is there a way to load them all without having to load each one with (responses["Question1"])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json
with open("main.json", "r") as f:
    responses = json.load(f)
    print(responses["Question1"])
```

In this approach all questions from JSON file will be read by json.load(f) instruction and stored within dictionary called responses. Keys of this dict will be question names f.e "Question1" and values will be question contents f.e "What is your name?".
When we have more questions we can iterate over them:

```
import json
with open("main.json", "r") as f:
    responses = json.load(f)
    for question_name, question_content in responses.items():
        print(question_content)
```

So for this JSON file:

```
{
  "Question1": "What is your name?",
  "Question2": "What is your age?"
}
```

it will print:

```
What is your name?
What is your age?
```

Comment: IS there are 10 questions, is there a way to load them all without having to load each one with (responses["Question1"])

Comment: All questions are loaded once with json.load(f) instruction. Then we operate on dictionary where key is question name f.e. "Question1" and value is question content f.e "What is your name?"